# Is it possible to calculate the average kinetic energy of an atomic orbital in an heavy atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

I am trying to calculate cross sections for electron impact ionization in heavy atoms (Xe and I) using a BEB technique. To do this I need, for each occupied orbital, occupancy number, binding energy and **average kinetic energy**. I can obtain the first two (to an acceptable degree of accuracy) using an Hartree-Fock (HF) calculation (I used the pyscf library). However it is not entirely clear to me how I would go about calculating the last term, the avg kinetic energy.

Is it something that I could obtain from an HF calculation, or is a more complex methodology needed?

I am fairly new to the field, so any reading recommendation on this issue is also appreciated.

Edit: In the original paper describing BEB, I found the average kinetic energy described as $U \equiv  <\vec{p}^2> /2m$, with $\vec{p}$ being the momentum operator of the electron in the subshell. My question remains, if modified: is it possible to obtain the mean value of the momentum operator in a given subshell?

Comment: If you have the wave function $\psi(x)$ for an orbital, then isn't the expectation value of the kinetic energy just $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \iiint \psi^* \nabla^2 \psi \, d^3 x$?  Or is $\psi(x)$ not something that comes out of your HF (Hartree-Fock?) calculations?

Comment: From what I can understand (again, very new to the field), Hartree-Fock provides me with a Fock operator, which itself is a sum of the kinetic energy, internuclear repulsion energy, nuclear-electronic Coulomb attraction terms and electron-electron Coulomb repulsion. All in a mean-field approach. The question would then be how to extract the kinetic energy from said sum, if it is possible

Comment: In principle, you could assign a $t_i=\langle\phi_i|\hat{t}|\phi_i\rangle$ kinetic energy to the $i$-th HF orbital. However, that value alone would be ill-defined, since it would not be invariant under unitary transformations among orbitals (like $\phi'_i=\sum_{k=1}^NU_{ki}\phi_k$). Observables of the total $N$-particle system (such as $E_{HF}$ or the full kinetic energy $\langle\Phi_{HF}|\hat{T}|\Phi_{HF}\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{N}t_i$) are invariant, but quantities associated with single electrons are not. You need additional conditions imposed on the HF orbitals to make $t_i$ unique.

Comment: That is an interesting observation, and one that I will have to look into! Someone on the pyscf github told me how to extract the average kinetic energy (for posterity: by contracting the orbital coefficients C = mf.mo_coeff with the kinetic energy matrix T = mol.intor_symmetric('int1e_kin') ) and the numbers match those found in the literature, so that looks promising. Thank you for the pointers!